# How to write multiple queries in 'Order' clause with limits defined in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model 'Product'. My requirement is to get a list of all products, but the top 20 products should be in the order of `created_at` and all remaining ones should be in the order of `updated_at`.

Right now my query is `Product.order('created_at DESC,updated_at DESC')`, but this gives me all products in order of `created_at`.

I thought about using a `limit` clause inside `order` clause. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: what did you try to filter products?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in SQL. Unless you use UNION or just plain two queries.

Comment: How do you define "top" products?

Comment: Also, which rails is it?

Comment: My rails version is 4.2.1, i didn't define top products. i want to get all products but first 10 should be based on 'created_at' and next 10 in the order of 'updated_at'

Comment: I changed some sentence structuring to remove unneccessary words and try to make them more clear. Also some more code tagging and additonal paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it :

```
top_ten_products = Product.order(:created_at).limit(10)
next_ten_products = Product.where.not(id: top_ten_products).order(:updated_at).limit(10)
products = top_ten_products + next_ten_products
```

- `top_ten_products` is fetching the 10 first products, ordered by created_at in ascending order.
- `next_ten_products` is fetching the first 10 products, ordered by updated_at in ascending order, and excluding the top_ten_products.
- `products` is the union of both arrays